# Pastebin Terminal Syntax

Tags: syntax-highlighting, pastebin

Just curious:

If I'm pasting the output of some terminal processes—like the various commands one goes through to make and install a certain driver or application—into the [Ubuntu Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/), what syntax would one choose to make it the most readable?

You know, to make it clearer when the user has issued a command and when the computer is logging events.

Is there one that will make the output [as pretty as it is in Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMPG0.png)?

Comment: None, for me. No need to force highlighting where there's no common structure.

Comment: Thanks for your 2¢, @muru. I just ask for curiosity sake—wondering if there was an option that would keep that green _ubuntu@ubuntu_ pleasant-looking and distinctive from the rest of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Plain Text would be my choice as Syntax Highlighting is mostly used to tell apart distinct syntactical elements and the output of a command has none of these.