# ALSA unable to list playback devices and issues with PulseAudio default output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I'm in need of help to figure out the proper audio configuration on linux, specifically on my Lubuntu box, running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and kernel:
Linux 4.4.0-93-generic #116-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux

The system is fully updated.

Having spent a few hours configuring and troubleshooting both ALSA and Pulseaudio, I've managed to get things working to an acceptable degree, although I'm somewhat stuck on the following two issues:

Firstly, I get the sense that something's wrong with the configuration of ALSA on my system, as I'm currently unable to list any playback devices using:

`aplay -l`

This is the output I get:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
ALSA lib conf.c:3357:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
ALSA lib control.c:954:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:0
aplay: device_list:277: control open (0): No such file or directory
```

Should this be considered a problem (and in that case, how do I fix it?) or can it be safely ignored?

The second issue is more of a functional one, being that I would like my TV speakers to be the default output device (sink?), when my headphones aren't connected.
This only halfway works at the moment, as, after a reboot, I need to plug-in and then unplug my headphones, for sound to be played on the TV speakers (connected via HDMI). 
After re-plugging the headphones, however, auto switching works seamlessly.

Any ideas as to what might be wrong and how to correct it?

Here's a link to a copy of the contents of my Pulseaudio "default.pa" file: https://pastebin.com/KzDfe8a3

And here's the output from `ls -l /dev/snd/`:

`drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       60 Sep 12 23:37 by-path
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 Sep 12 23:37 controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 Sep 12 23:37 hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  9 Sep 12 23:37 hwC0D3
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 Sep 12 23:37 pcmC0D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 Sep 13 00:09 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 Sep 12 23:37 pcmC0D2p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 Sep 12 23:37 pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 Sep 12 23:37 pcmC0D7p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Sep 12 23:37 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Sep 12 23:37 timer`

My personal user is member of the audio group.

Contents of `~/.asoundrc`:

`# --auto-generated-- by /etc/kodi/live.d/01-make-asoundrc.sh`
`# AUTOUPDATE=True  # change this to disable updating of this file`
`pcm.!default {
  type plug;
  slave.pcm "plughw:CARD=DAC,DEV=0";`

Comment: Please attach `lshw -C sound` and `amixer contents` output, too. Use [pastebin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895467/pastebin-terminal-syntax) to the second command, due to length of the output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need help to figure out audio configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/955215/need-help-to-figure-out-audio-configuration)

Comment: @Redbob
Sorry. Somehow I managed to post twice. I've deleted the other post now.

Comment: Reinstall `alsa`, `pulseaudio` and `pavucontrol`. See if works

Comment: Here's the output from `lshw -C sound`:


`*-multimedia            
       description: Audio device
       product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:31 memory:f7c10000-f7c13fff `

Comment: `amixer contents` returns only the following (which to me, again, indicates something is broken in ALSA): 

`ALSA lib conf.c:3357:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
ALSA lib control.c:954:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default
amixer: Control default open error: No such file or directory `

Comment: You must reinstall these software I told you before

Comment: I already tried reinstalling ALSA and even tried another version of this component, but the error persists. PulseAudio has also been reinstalled, so I don't think doing that again is going to make any difference.
If you insist, though, I can try it once again...

Comment: Should have probably mentioned that in the post - my apologies.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /dev/snd/`? Do you have access rights for these device nodes? Does "working" mean that both PulseAudio and `aplay` work?

Comment: Output of ls -l /dev/snd/ added to question above, due to character limit in comments.

Comment: What would be the best way of checking if PulseAudio and aplay are working properly? I can play audio through both my headphone and HDMI outputs, so overall, the sound output seems to work just fine, in spite of the error and possible misconfiguration as described in my question.

Comment: @CL 

Do you have a reply to my question above?

Comment: Did you change anything in the ALSA configuration files (`/etc/asound.conf` or `~/.asoundrc`)? If yes, show them.

Comment: Nope, /etc/asound-conf doesn't exist on my system and I haven't changed ~/.asoundrc directly (contents of which are added to the question above). From the contents of .asoundrc, however, it _is_ apparent that the KODI media center software which is installed on my machine, has edited the file at some point, and I _have_ been editing sound settings via that application.

Comment: Do you have an idea as to what I should do from here? I really hope you're able to help me along but if you consider the issues I'm experiencing to be related or caused by the KODI installation I will of course bring my question to their forum instead.